# Registering to PyPi: basic auth failed

Tags: python-2.7, distutils, setup.py, pypi, cheeseshop

I can't figure out how to register my project. I can login in fine at https://testpypi.python.org/pypi but using the same credentials at my .pypirc doesn't work.

**.pypirc**

```
[distutils]
index-servers=
    test

[test]
repository = https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username = <username>
password = <password>
```

`<username>` and `<password>` are replaced with the credentials I use to login manually at testpypi.

Then I try to register my project:

```
python setup.py register -r test
```

**Output**

```
running register
running egg_info
writing websocket_server.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to websocket_server.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to websocket_server.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'websocket_server.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'websocket_server.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
Registering myproject to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (401): basic auth failed
```

Any idea what is going on? I looked everywhere but there seems to be very little information on how to troubleshoot such issues.

Answer (score 5):

You need to complete the registration by clicking the link in your email.

Comment: Problem is that I never received such a link.. In the end I gave up the testpypi server and did the same at the official server. It worked fine there.

Comment: This solved my issue. I never completed that process. I just made sure I was able to login to the test server. I went back and I checked the "I agree" checkbox and everything went fine.

Comment: In case some else (like me) thinks: *"I can log-in into the web site with these very same credentials, so this can't be it, right?!* Stop thinking. Just check your mails.

Comment: It seems like the issue moves around, I had this because I went to the wrong URL it seems.  See [issue comment here](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/2065#issuecomment-329056218) if you never received the confirmation e-mail like @Pithikos and I.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a token, your username should be `__token__`
I've been on this for at least four hours and then came across this guide that mentioned the username check.
https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth